# Tabbarcontroller add tabs programmatically

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller

For the app i am building i have all of my Views done in a storyboard and it is using a tabbarcontrolller to switch between the different views. I have one view that i want to programmatically add to this already existing tab bar which already has three items. How can I programmatically add this tab and leave the other tabs be through the storyboard.

More: I did what the you said but nothing happened when i added that it still only has three tabs rather than adding the fourth here is the code i have for the tab bar controller

```
@interface TheTabBarController ()

@end

@implementation TheTabBarController


- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    UIViewController *viewController = [[CrewsViewController alloc]init];
    NSMutableArray *tempArray = [self.tabBarController.viewControllers mutableCopy];
    [tempArray addObject:viewController];
    self.tabBarController.viewControllers = tempArray;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 3):

You do this by adding a new controller to the tab bar controller's `viewControllers` array. So, instantiate the new controller by whatever means is appropriate for how you make the controller. The `viewControllers` property of a tab bar controller is a immutable array, so you need to create a mutable array from this array, add your controller to it, then set this array to be the tab bar controller's `viewControllers` array.

```
UIViewController *newController = [[UIViewController alloc] init]; // or however is appropriate to instantiate your controller
NSMutableArray *tempArray = [self.tabBarController.viewControllers mutableCopy];
[tempArray addObject:newController];
self.tabBarController.viewControllers = tempArray;
```

Comment: i did what you said and nothing happened can you check to see if i did anything wrong. i posted the code for the tab bar controller above.

Comment: i tried to log the tempArray and for some reason it is null. im not sure but does this have to do with the issue?

Comment: @user3499627, I was assuming that you were doing it from one of the content controllers, not the tab bar controller. You need to replace self.tabBarController with self (self.tabBarController will be nil inside the tab bar controller).

Answer (score 1):

**Try this:**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIViewController *view1 = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
    UIViewController *view2 = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
    UIViewController *view3 = [[UIViewController alloc] init];

    NSMutableArray *tabViewControllers = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [tabViewControllers addObject:view1];
    [tabViewControllers addObject:view2];
    [tabViewControllers addObject:view3];

    [self setViewControllers:tabViewControllers];
    //can't set this until after its added to the tab bar
    view1.tabBarItem = 
      [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"view1" 
                                    image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"view1"] 
                                      tag:1];
    view2.tabBarItem = 
      [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"view2" 
                                    image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"view3"] 
                                      tag:2];
    view3.tabBarItem = 
      [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"view3" 
                                    image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"view3"] 
                                      tag:3];      
}
```

Answer (score 0):

swift4:

`func viewDidLoad() {`

```
super.viewDidLoad()
let view1 = UIViewController()
let view2 = UIViewController()
let view3 = UIViewController()
var tabViewControllers = [AnyHashable]()
tabViewControllers.append(view1)
tabViewControllers.append(view2)
tabViewControllers.append(view3)
if let aControllers = tabViewControllers as? [UIViewController] {
    viewControllers = aControllers
}

//can't set this until after its added to the tab bar

`view1.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: "view1", image: UIImage(named: "view1"), tag: 1)
view2.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: "view2", image: UIImage(named: "view3"), tag: 2)
view3.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: "view3", image: UIImage(named: "view3"), tag: 3)
```

`}`